# Get the value of text of header(HTML,CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Now I have to click on subscribe button and get the value of the plan name that is either Platinum or Gold.

**HTML:**

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active col-md-9" id="home">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <table class="table table-bordered Pricing-Plan" style="background: #E8FFD2;">
            <tr>
                <th style="background: #60D760;">
                    <h3 class="Plan">Platinum</h3>
                    <p>AGENCIES & MARKETING TEAMS</p>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="table-price">$299</p>
                    <span>per month</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success pricing-button">Subscribe</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <table class="table table-bordered Pricing-Plan">
            <tr>
                <th style="background: #22D3FF;">
                    <h3 class="Plan">Gold</h3>
                    <p>CONSULTANTS & SMALL BUSINESSES</p>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="table-price">$199</p>
                    <span>per month</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-info pricing-button">Subscribe</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $(".pricing-button").click(function() {
        alert($(this).find('.Pricing-Plan Plan').text());
        //$('.Plan').val(function () {
        //    $(this).text();
        //});
    });
});
```

I need to get price and plan name on Subscribe button click, I hope someone help me out with this.

Comment: You can pass "Plan" to your javascript method on click of button. Or set data-plan="xyz" on button and get in event handler.

Comment: Or simply change your script to : alert($(this).parents('table').find('.Plan').html());

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/parkashkumar37/bw402br1/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/parkashkumar37/6ffjqp30/

Comment: Yes solved using alert($(this).parents('table').find('.Plan').html());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by slightly modifying your code to:

```
$(".pricing-button").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parents('table').find('.Plan').html());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/parkashkumar37/bw402br1/)

OR

You can add custom attribute `data-plan="Plantinum/Gold"` to your pricing button as:

```
<span class="btn btn-info pricing-button" data-plan="Gold">Subscribe</span>
```

And get attribute value as following:

```
$(".pricing-button").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-plan'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/parkashkumar37/6ffjqp30/)

Comment: @Jot, Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
$(function () {
        $(".pricing-button").click(function () {
            alert($(this).closest('.Pricing-Plan').find('.Plan').text());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this way .

**Used to this**

```
$(this).parents('table').find('.Plan').html();
```

**Demo**

```js
 $(function () {
            $(".pricing-button").click(function () {

                var htmlString =$(this).parents('table').find('.Plan').html();
            
               alert( htmlString );
                //$('.Plan').val(function () {
                //    $(this).text();
                //});
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active col-md-9" id="home">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered Pricing-Plan" style="background: #E8FFD2;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background: #60D760;">
                                                <h3 class="Plan">Platinum</h3>
                                                <p>
                                                    AGENCIES & MARKETING
                                                    <br />
                                                    TEAMS
                                                </p>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <p class="table-price">$299</p>
                                                <span>per month</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="btn btn-success pricing-button">Subscribe</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered Pricing-Plan">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="background: #22D3FF;">
                                                <h3 class="Plan">Gold</h3>
                                                <p>CONSULTANTS & SMALL BUSINESSES</p>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <p class="table-price">$199</p>
                                                <span>per month</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><span class="btn btn-info pricing-button">Subscribe</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following way to get price and package name.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="btn btn-success pricing-button" onClick="$(this).MessageBox('platinum','$299');">Subscribe</span>

<span class="btn btn-info pricing-button" onClick="$(this).MessageBox('gold','$199');">Subscribe</span>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$.fn.MessageBox = function(package,price) {
        alert(package + " has price " + price);
    };
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02vjhLj0/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$(".pricing-button").click(function () {
      alert($(this).closest('.col-sm-4').find('.Plan').text()); 
});
```